# How to get text of children tag's description using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using beautiful soup to scrape some data from 
[foodily.com](http://www.foodily.com/r/0y1ygzt3zf-perfect-vanilla-cupcakes-by-annie-s)

On above page there is a `div` with class 'ings' and I want to get data within its `p` tags for that I have written below code:

```
ingredients = soup.find('div', {"class": "ings"}).findChildren('p')
```

It provide me list of ingredient but with `p` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) for every `p` element found inside the `div` element with `class="ings"`.

Complete working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update({"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36"})
    response = session.get("http://www.foodily.com/r/0y1ygzt3zf-perfect-vanilla-cupcakes-by-annie-s")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    ingredients = [ingredient.get_text() for ingredient in soup.select('div.ings p')]
    print(ingredients)
```

Prints:

```
[
    u'For the cupcakes:', 
    u'1 stick (113g) butter/marg*', 
    u'1 cup caster sugar', u'2 eggs', 
    ...
    u'1 tbsp vanilla extract', 
    u'2-3tbsp milk', 
    u'Sprinkles to decorate, optional'
]
```

Note that I've also improved your locator a bit and switched to a `div.ings p` [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


url = "http://www.foodily.com/r/0y1ygzt3zf-perfect-vanilla-cupcakes-by-annie-s"
source = requests.get(url)
text_new = source.text
soup = bs(text_new, "html.parser")
ingredients  = soup.findAll('div', {"class": "ings"})
for a in ingredients :
    print (a.text)
```

It will print:

```
For the cupcakes:

1 stick (113g) butter/marg*

1 cup caster sugar

2 eggs

1 tbsp vanilla extract

1 and 1/2 cups plain flour

2 tsp baking powder

1/2 cup milk (I use Skim)

For the frosting:

2 sticks (226g) unsalted butter, at room temp

2 and 1/2 cups icing sugar, sifted

1 tbsp vanilla extract

2-3tbsp milk

Sprinkles to decorate, optional
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the list of `p` tags, use `get_text()`. This will return only the text of them:

```
ingredient_list = p.get_text() for p in ingredients
```

The result array will look like:

```
ingredient_list = [
   'For the cupcakes:', '1 stick (113g) butter/marg*', 
   '1 cup caster sugar','2 eggs', ...
]
```